# How to monitor my hosted Git repo for single file changes by others?

Tags: git, github, gitlab

What methods are available for being notified when a specific path changes by whatever method (push, merge), on a specific branch in a git repo I have write access to?

I'm looking for a brief introductory summary of the notification capabilities of repos hosted at Github or Gitlab. I am trying to decide where to host my project, and the ability to monitor changes is critical to me.

The repo to be published/hosted is large, and I expect will be widely forked, as well as have several contributors with direct write access, so the ability to filter notifications by branch and filename are essential.

Comment: It seems more flexible to use `git fetch` plus some local application that checks for these changes. That way you can implement anything you want instead of whatever API that the host platform has exposed.

Comment: you want to know about changes in forks too? (pretty sure that would make things significantly more complicated)

Answer (score 0):

To accomplish this task you have to write a **server hook**, but it depends on your **git** host platform like example **Gitlab** or **Github**.

Here you can find some documentation for Gitlab: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/server_hooks.html .

Here for Github https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-server@3.7/admin/policies/enforcing-policy-with-pre-receive-hooks/creating-a-pre-receive-hook-script .

Comment: Its Github, thanks!

Also, i need this to be done on all the available GOT branches.

Comment: I added a link to the Github documentation which you have to study on your own.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to accomplish this. Which one is best depends on how you relate to the project, and what you want done. You say that you want an email, but that is a most elementary thing that can be done. I anticipate that once you learn how to get a notification, you will want to implement some specified action in response. Here are some higher-level things that can be done when a push is made:

1. **GitHub "Actions"** are specifically designed to take some action on some defined event. GitHub runs the logic/algorithm on their servers and you get the results (ie, GitHub hosts the processing). Check out the [Monitoring actions](https://github.com/marketplace?type=actions) category of the [Marketplace](https://github.com/marketplace). Some samples that seem to fit your bill:

   - [PagerDuty Change Events](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/pagerduty-change-events)
   - [Commit Hawk](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/commithawk)
   - ... many more
2. **A Github "App"** can do even more. On various triggers (including a basic push), your application (You host the processing) receives a "WebHook" which is a notification that some event happened (The webhook can be configured to be sent on just about any event you can imagine, and then some). The application can do any number of things at this time, including checking the change, and possibly opening a new issue if a problem is found. If the trigger you're watching is a "pull request" rather than a "push", the App can perform a "review" and "approve", "reject" or "request changes" before the PR is accepted. For a push, it could submit a pull request, or even make a commit. An app can do just about anything that a human can do, subject to what actions the repo owner wants and allows.

   In a nutshell, an "App" can automate whatever you would "do" when you receive that notification email.

   Examples:

   - [GitGuardian](https://github.com/marketplace/gitguardian) - automates removal of passwords and secrets from the codebase
   - [GitLocalise](https://github.com/marketplace/gitlocalize) - automates translation whenever user-visible text or documentation changes in the codebase.

   There are a lot of Apps in the [Monitoring Apps](https://github.com/marketplace?category=monitoring&type=apps) category; Once you discover it is possible to automate the process of reviewing pushes, you will likely want more complex things done; there might already be an app for that. If not, you can also [create an app](https://github.com/settings/apps) to do exactly what you want done.

   Apps, as opposed to Actions, enable you to have work done on your data/repo using logic that you don't have. Eg, suppose there is an app that is able to remove all bugs from a codebase. It might be a proprietary, closely guarded algorithm. If the owner of that algorithm provides it as an "App", you can "install" it, and get the work done on your repo, even though you might not have the "secret sauce".
3. GitHub has built-in support for **[CODEOWNERS](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/managing-your-repositorys-settings-and-features/customizing-your-repository/about-code-owners)** which is a file you put in your repo which describe which people own which pieces of the puzzle/codebase. The repo can be set to to automatically request the approval of code owners before pull requests are merged, for instance. In your question you're looking for post-push notification, rather than a pre-merge review/approval process, so CODEOWNERS may or may not be what you're looking for.